# A silly beginner question

Tags: solidity, remix

I am just a new learner and was trying to replicate the steps from a video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tonsx0O_InA) introducing solidity as follows:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;


contract DumbCoin1{

    address deployer;
    mapping(address=>uint) balances;

    function DumbCoin1(){

        deployer = msg.sender;

    }

    function giveCoins(uint amount, address receiver){

        if(msg.sender == deployer){
            // give coins to receiver
            balances[receiver] += amount;
        }
        else{
            throw;
        }

    }


    function viewBalance() returns (uint){

        return balances[msg.sender];

    }

}
```

However, after I clicked the button 'publish on swarm', and tested the giveCoins and viewBalances functions. seems that error occurs as belows:

```
creation of DumbCoin1 pending...
[vm] from:0xca3...a733c, to:DumbCoin1.(constructor), value:0 wei, data:0x606...e0029, 0 logs, hash:0x02a...50bae
Details
Debug
transact to DumbCoin1.viewBalance pending ... 
[vm] from:0xca3...a733c, to:DumbCoin1.viewBalance() 0x692...77b3a, value:0 wei, data:0x3ff...1e05b, 0 logs, hash:0x923...1aaaf
Details
Debug
transact to DumbCoin1.giveCoins errored: Error encoding arguments: SyntaxError: Unexpected token x in JSON at position 7
```

What is the reason for the failure and how should I fix it?

Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you used Remix to call these functions and your arguments for `giveCoins` looked something like this:

```
123, 0xabc123789
```

Remix expects multiple arguments to be passed as a JSON array (but without the square brackets). Hexadecimal values must be quoted strings. Try adding quotes around the address:

```
123, "0xabc123789"
```

Comment: Thanks, seems works for me. And also just want to confirm, as from the video, the output / result after clicking the button are shown besides the button. However, when I tried to do it today, all the functions of non ERC20 functions are only reflected in the grey column of the pages, and stated that the transaction is pending. But actually it works as i can confirm the transfer amount by clicking the ERC 20 functions (such as "total supply" and "balance of ". Why is it like this? Thanks!

Comment: That sounds like a new question: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask. (It's hard for others to benefit from a question asked and answered in comments.)

Comment: Sorry, I will amend and ask as a new question later, thanks!